# Oracle SQL Developer - Export Schema for use in Apache Derby

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, derby

I'm trying to export an existing Oracle SQL database schema so that I can use it to build up an Apache Derby database.

Whenever I use the "Database Export" functionality of SQL Developer 4.0.1.14, it generates the sql files, but they are in a format that Apache Derby cannot work with.

Does anybody know of any way to export the schema so that that format is compatible with Apache Derby?

Examples:
Apache Derby wants something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "SURVEY"."LOAD_BALANCE" 
   (    "LOAD_BALANCE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SURVEY_ID" NUMBER, 
    "ROUTING_SERVICES" VARCHAR(255), 
    "ALGORITHM" VARCHAR(255), 
    "WEIGHT" VARCHAR(255), 
    "STICKINESS" VARCHAR(255), 
    "HEALTH_MONITOR" VARCHAR(255), 
    "SSL_USED" VARCHAR(255)
   )
```

But SQL Developer outputs it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "SURVEY"."LOAD_BALANCE" 
   (    "LOAD_BALANCE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "SURVEY_ID" NUMBER, 
    "ROUTING_SERVICES" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "ALGORITHM" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "WEIGHT" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "STICKINESS" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "HEALTH_MONITOR" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "SSL_USED" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try DdlUtils: http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/

I know it supports Derby, and the project website says it supports Oracle, so ...

Comment: Bryan-

  Yeah I had tried to look into DdlUtils earlier today but the download site and all of its mirrors are apparently down.  Haven't been able to download it all day.

http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/download.html

Comment: Well, the internet as a whole seems to suggest that this is the way to go.  However I still cannot access the DdlUtils library from a reputable source.  My colleagues and I have decided to go another route.  Thanks for you reply Bryan.